# Is there a way to make d3 scale.range dynamic so that it works with window resizing?

Tags: d3.js

I am making a table that contains sparklines (simple d3 line charts). I set the width of the svg to 100% which ensures the svg grows and shrinks should the user change the browser window size, and the table shrink or expand:

```
d3.select(@el).select('#week-trend').append("svg").attr("width", "100%")...
```

**is there a way to do something similar for the range of the x-scale?**

as of now it is hard-coded to a value that works on page load, but causes the graph to get clipped, or not fill up the entire svg should the user change the browser window size:

```
x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, xMax]).range([0, 100])
```

Comment: Have a look at how [nvd3 does it](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/utils.js#L32). The basic idea is binding to the `resize` event of the window, resizing the container (as a function of window size) and then redrawing the plot.

Comment: Simply use something dynamic like `window.innerWidth` to determine the range.

Answer (score 0):

it would be better to get the svg responsive I think, in that case you would need to add in the css:

```
#svg{
    width:75%; //the % you want the svg div to be
    height: auto;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    }
```

and then in the script you create the svg this way:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("div")
            .attr("id", "svg")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height )
            .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin");
```

of course set up a width and height variable.

**EDIT:** sorry did not understand that you already got the svg responsive

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use percentage positioning instead of pixels. So create your range as normal (but as a percentage of the svg you want to use—so probably not 0 to 100), but inside your data loop, use `.attr('x', function(d) { return x(d) + '%'; })`. These percentages will scale along with the containing svg.

(Make sure to continue to use pixel values for stuff like text sizes, though!)

Comment: there is no 'data loop', at least not in the way that i think you mean. i simply append a path to my svg, and pass line([array of my data]) as the 'd" attribute of the path.

Comment: Ah—yeah, you can't use percentages with svg paths. You could use a polyline, but that's not as convenient.